# Vanishing variable content in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

Basically my problem is this, I have and interaction with several divs that change into different colors, depending if the mouse is over them or not. But all of them call the same function, which will perform differently depending on a global flag set by the user, earlier in pipeline.
The problem is the flag's value becomes undefined, like so:

```
var flag = true;

$("#btn0").on('mouseover', function(){

    alert(flag) // true
    btnRollover(0);
});

function btnRollover(ID){

    alert(flag) // undefined
}
```

The same problem happens with all the other variables I need to use later on, but what baffles me is I have 2 other interactions with a similar structure that work perfectly!
Does anyone have any idea what can be causing this?

P.S: I can't post the full thing because: 1) I don't have permission to do so; 2) the full thing is over 15.000 lines of code.

Comment: You must be doing something to "flag" in one of those lines... I tried replicating the above and it works perfectly, so not sure you can be helped without more information.

Comment: I can't reproduce this based on the code you've provided: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Mq49A/

Comment: check your flag elsewhere or pass the flag to your functions.

Comment: I've checked several times, the flag isn't being changed anywhere, only read. And like I said I used the same structure before and it worked perfectly too. Reason why I don't understand why it's not working on this one

Comment: see the scopes of both flag and ID variables http://jsfiddle.net/8saKp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hazard a guess, I suspect you might be scoping your flag variable to a ready event handler (or some other handler), such that it isn't actually global, and declaring your function outside that ready event handler. Something like:

```
$(function() { // this is the start of the ready event handler
    var flag = true;
    $("#btn0").on('mouseover', function(){

      alert(flag); // flag is in scope
      btnRollover(0);
   });     
}); // end of ready event handler

function btnRollover(ID) {
    alert(flag); // flag is NOT in scope
}
```

... if this is correct, then you need to declare you flag and your function in the same scope (i.e. either both in the ready event or both outside of it).

Answer (score 2):

Below are some troubleshooting steps I would take if I had the full code, give them a try.  Also, have you checked the console for errors?  What is the actual error you receive in the console when this problem arises?

1) search the entire page for "flag", make sure nothing else is setting it or changing it in any way you didn't expect

2) examine the scope in which `var flag = true;` appears.  Is it on page load? go to next troubleshooting step, otherwise, if its inside a method or something else with a more local scope get it out of there and make it more global.

Comment: In the full version what I have is an empty, global flag that receives the value from the user (the rollover code is only called afterwards and) and there's no other place where the value is being changed.

Comment: As for errors it doesn't accuse any, except the value being undefined

Comment: can you paste the exact error, and any line number references or anything else that came with it?

Comment: "TypeError: interactionList[currentInteraction][ID] is undefined. Line 3236" The problem is with the currentInteraction, which is a value passed in the same manner as the flag. What I don't understand is why the flag, and all the other global variables, vanish

Comment: well this is why i asked.  That error doesn't necessarily point to the "flag", or "currentInteraction" having disappeared.  It points more to the possibility that interactionList array doesn't exist. Or that the position in the array its referring to is undefined.  I would console.log the crap out of that area, print everything in question and see what is actually undefined.  Also, flag is boolean in your example but being used as an int here... unless its a mixed multidimensional array. seems odd.

Comment: i would try putting a console.log at the code there to be sure you're hitting it, and replace currentInteraction with true just for giggles... if the error still is thrown then its not currentInteraction.

Comment: No, those I know currentInteraction exists because it's used repeatedly all over the code with no problems so far. As for the boolean flag, it's the first global variable used, but because it was in an if it didn't accuse an error

Comment: how is my #2 suggestion in my answer different from what was accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem.
1. I think you should search for flag make sure nothing else is setting it as erikrunia suggested.
2. second is I think you have declared the variable in $(document).ready function so when you tried to access it in the function which is outside the documetn.ready function that means it scope is not in function I think you should declare the flag at the top of jquery just below the script tag.

Example

```
 <div class="test" id="1">test1</div>  
 <div class="test" id="2">test2</div> 
 <div class="test" id="3">test3</div> 
 <div class="test" id="4">test4</div>  

<script>
var flag=true;

$(".test").on('mouseover', function(){

    alert(flag) // true
    btnRollover($(this).attr("id"));
});

function btnRollover(ID){
 alert("ID="+ID)
    alert("flat="+flag) // undefined
}

</script>
```